# How to fix my oracle'sql about search date range?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have `textbox1` and `textbox2` on my page. `textbox1` is for campaign's start date. `textbox2` is for campaign's end date.

If campaign's start date(`textbox1`) is 2022/06/23, end date(`textbox2`) is 2022/06/25, when I input start date(`textbox1`) is 2022/06/01, end date(`textbox2`) is 2022/07/01, I have to get the "campaign's start date(`textbox1`) is 2022/06/23, end date(`textbox2`) is 2022/06/25," show on the page, but I also get the start date(`textbox1`) is 2022/07/01, end date(`textbox2`) is 2022/07/02, but this is wrong, I can't get the campaign start date and end date is not in the 2022/06/01~2022/07/01.

My current Oracle SQL in C# is this:

```cs
SqlStr = select start date, end date, campaign_name 
        from campaign_table 
        where to_char(ATUL_EFF_DT,'yyyy/MM/dd') >= '1900/01/01' and to_char(ATUL_EXP_DT,'yyyy/MM/dd') <= '9999/12/28' ";
```

and the param is:

```cs
pO_params.Add("@start date", TextBox1.Text);
pO_params.Add("@end date", TextBox2.Text);
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Maybe not convert the date to a string to compare, but convert the string literal to a date?

Comment: You cannot have spaces in parameter names. And you shouldn't have spaces in column names

Comment: Please specify the exact issue you have. Do you have any errors? Then provide the error message and code. Does the query return what you expect when executed in SQL console? If not, then C# is irrelevant here. Are parameters passed correctly? If no, then you need to debug this process  by moving parameters from the `where` clause to the `select` list and using `dual` table to avoid any data type conversions. Anyway, dates should be passed as dates and be filled by date picker, not text input field

Comment: Please fix your formatting as well: indents mean "format as code", so don't use that on plain text - watch the live preview as you edit.

Answer (score 0):

there is a space between the "start date" and "end date" columns, correct the field name should work.